# Scale Background CSS with Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working with some CSS Backgrounds (http://css3pie.com/demos/gradient-patterns/) in an application and want to be able to scale the design with a slider. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L3d9qh2/). I was able to scale X & Y separately on some like the Stripes and Picnic designs where I just had to play with `background-size:50px 50px;` like this:

```
//setup the variables based off the css which was set using dropdown
gridItems = $(document.activeElement).val().split("; ");
for (i = 0; i < gridItems.length -1; i++) {
    gridSettings = gridItems[i].split(":");

    if (gridSettings[0]=="background-size"){
        gridSize = gridSettings[1].split(" ");
        gridX = gridSize[0];
        gridY = gridSize[1]
        }
   //on the action of the slide - update value
    $('#gridXY-'+key).on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
        gridXY = slideEvt.value;
        $('.draggable-' + currentLayer).css("background-size", "calc("+ gridX +" * "+ gridXY +") calc("+ gridY +" * "+ gridXY +")");
    });
```

Which can be set either numerically or using  but when it gets to something like the Blue Print it has a lot more settings `background-size:100px 100px, 100px 100px, 20px 20px, 20px 20px;`

I am trying to do this right so that it can take a variable number of those, and can write something that could work, but the method I have in mind is really messy, hoping for some help scaling this that might be a little cleaner than what I would do.

I did find this:http://codepen.io/Erik/pen/JGnsB but he is using LESS to declare variables, if possible I would like to stay away from that.

UPDATE:
Here is a JSFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/4L3d9qh2/

I added a function that should have let me update it, but for some reason the calc() function doesn't seem to be working to update the div style. After processing, it looks like this:
`$('.draggable-0').css("background-size", calc(100px - 4) calc(100px - 4), calc(100px - 4) calc(100px - 4), calc(20px - 4) calc(20px - 4), calc(20px - 4) calc(20px - 4));`

```
$.each(gridSizeArray, function( k, v ){
            if (gridIncrement==1)
            {
                gridXY = "calc(" + v +" - " + value + ") ";
            }else{
                if(isOdd(gridIncrement)){
                gridXY = gridXY + "calc(" + v +" - " + value + ") ";
                }else{
                gridXY = gridXY + "calc(" + v +" - " + value + "), ";
                }
            }


            gridIncrement++
            })
```

Comment: A JSFiddle, code snippet or codepen would really help out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4L3d9qh2/

Comment: Not actually related to the question but, on codepen, if you click on the 'View complied' button, it shows the CSS not the LESS code.

Answer (score 0):

Here was the final code that works. Using .each() loop through and if it is even, add a comma, then remove the last comma at the end.

```
                gridItems = $(document.activeElement).val().split("; ");

                for (i = 0; i < gridItems.length -1; i++) {
                    gridSettings = gridItems[i].split(":");

                    if (gridSettings[0]=="background-size"){
                        gridSizeString = gridSettings[1].replace(/,/gi, '');
                        gridSizeArray = gridSizeString.split(" ");
                        }

                    $('[data-type="sliderLayer"][data-layer="'+currentLayer+'"][data-slide="'+currentSlide+'"]').css(gridSettings[0], gridSettings[1]);

                }

            $.each(gridSizeArray, function( k, v ){
            if (gridIncrement==1)
            {
                gridXY = "calc(" + v +" + " + value + "px) ";
            }else{
                if(isOdd(gridIncrement)){
                gridXY = gridXY + " calc(" + v +" + " + value + "px) ";
                }else{
                gridXY = gridXY + "calc(" + v +" + " + value + "px),";
                }
            }
            gridIncrement++
            })
            if (isOdd(gridIncrement))
                {
                    gridXY = gridXY.substring(0, gridXY.length - 1);
                }
```